# How to use shelf_router with shelf_static in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a web server using Shelf in Dart. I have successfully built any api. My router.dart looks like this:

```dart
import 'package:dart_shelf_server_sample/files/controller.dart';
import 'package:dart_shelf_server_sample/helpers/helpers.dart';
import 'package:dart_shelf_server_sample/posts/controller.dart';
import 'package:shelf/shelf.dart';
import 'package:shelf_router/shelf_router.dart';

Router routes() {
  var app = Router();

  app.get('/api', (Request request) {
    var response = {
      'message': 'Dart API is alive',
      'api_routes': ['/posts', '/posts/{id}']
    };
    return Response.ok(toJson(response));
  });

  app.get('/posts', (Request request) {
    return PostController().find();
  });

  app.get('/posts/<id>', (Request request, String id) {
    return PostController().findOne(id);
  });

  app.get('/files/<name>', (Request request, String name) {
    return FileController().findOne(name);
  });

  return app;
}
```

Here is my server.dart:

```dart
import 'package:dart_shelf_server_sample/config/constants.dart';
import 'package:dart_shelf_server_sample/config/routes.dart';
import 'package:shelf/shelf_io.dart' as io;

void main(List<String> args) async {
  var app = routes();
  var server = await io.serve(app, hostname, port);
  print('Serving at http://${server.address.host}:${server.port}');
}
```

Now, what I am trying to achieve is to serve files from the webserver based on the requested path through a custom **FileController** class. How do I use shelf_static to implement this feature?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
app.mount('/files/', createStaticHandler('path/to/static/files'));
```

If you have a file `path/to/static/files/index.html` it will be served for the request `/files/index.html`.